# How to handle different categorical embedding sizes in hold out data set

Tags: categorical-data, pytorch, embeddings

I have a pytorch tabular dataset with zip code as a categorical embedding.  I'm getting great results on the test set.  When I go to run my hold out sample through, it errors out because I have more zip codes in the hold out then what the model was trained on.

How do I handle this?  In production, the likelihood of seeing a new zip code is high so I need to learn something I can transfer into production.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to represent the zip codes using some transformation that could be applied to new (unseen) zip codes as well. For example, could you re-represent zip codes as latitude + longitude?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a unseen zipcode in your training data (represented by a value like -1) and then train the model. The model would then be able to handle unseen zipcode values in the test data set.

Comment: That's interesting in regards to other categorical variables. How does the model know if new data is unseen?  Are you envisioning some sort of look up table with all seen values?